# Call native code when a JS value is garbage collected

Tags: cobalt

In my application I'm creating some JS objects, and also on C++ side some objects for running some handling.
I would like to **delete C++ objects when they are not needed anymore: the corresponding JS object is Garbage Collected**.

I'm trying to find that in Cobalt source code/documentation but I cannot find that. I do see ScriptValue::Reference but this seems to be the opposite:
Prevent a JS object from being garbage collected by declaring a relation between a JS value and C++ object.

Could someone give some hints how this can be achieved? (getting some callback called in C++ when an object is garbage collected).

Answer (score 0):

Any C++ class exposed to JavaScript must inherit (directly or indirectly) `script::Wrappable` which has a virtual destructor. This destructor will be called when a corresponding JavaScript object is destroyed, either as a result of garbage collection or JS VM teardown.

Usual caveats apply: GC order and timing are non-deterministic. If you need to free critical resources as soon as possible, expose explicit cleanup methods to JavaScript.

See `cobalt::dom::Node::~Node()` for example of a cleanup performed upon destruction.